# Simple Ajax Jquery script- How can I get information for each of the rows in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm following  a simple ajax>php>mysql example posted here http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

I can only display information from the first row.
My table is set up like so

```
--------------
|  id  | name|
--------------
| 1    | Pat |
| 2    | Joe |
| 3    | Rob |
--------------
```

The php code

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
 $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result  
 echo json_encode($array);
```

The script

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(data)        
      { 
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
         $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); 
      } 
    });
  });
```

**ROW 1**

If I put the `var id = data[0];` I get the value 1.
If I put the `var name = data[1];` I get Pat.

**ROWS 2 n 3 are undefined**

Example `var id=data[2];` returns undefined
etc

**My Questions**

1. Why do I only get the values from the first row?
2. How can I get information for rows other than the first one?

From other questions on Stackoverflow I see that I will probably have to use a while loop, but I'm not really sure why or how.

Comment: try using mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_row. Regards Jonas

Comment: Can you access the php page alone instead of doing by ajax request and tell us what the json echo prints on the screen?

Comment: @Jonas Thanks. I tried mysql_fetch_array but it still returned undefined for data[2],data[3],etc

Comment: @Guilherme Costa I got ["1","Pat"]

Comment: By the way all `mysql_fetch_*` functions return only 1 row!

Comment: @ComFreek Thanks. That's very useful! Looks like I've got a bit of PHP study to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**The old MySQL extension `mysql` is outdated, better use `mysqli` or `PDO`!**

[`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) returns only 1 row!
You have to put it into a loop, for example:

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

You also have to change the JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
  {
    for (var i in rows)
    {
      var row = rows[i];          

      var id = row[0];
      var vname = row[1];
      $('#output').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname)
                  .append("<hr />");
    } 
  } 
});
```

By the way I would recommend you to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) because it makes your code more flexible and cleaner.

Comment: @ComFreek The PHP seems to be working, because I get [["1","Pat"],["2","Joe"],["3","Rob"]] when I run the PHP. However, no result was displayed in #output. I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: is it possible to add auto refresh to this , to refresh the div, table , etc. whatever the object is at a defined interval, like 5 sec. ?

Comment: @kayhanyüksel Yes, it's possible. There would be 2 techniques: **a)** *Pull* the data regularly from the server (PHP script). Use either 'normal' AJAX request and [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) or use [long polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code). **b)** *Push* the data, i.e. use WebSockets. There are many good resources on the internet, for example: http://www.websocket.org/

Answer (score 0):

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$array = array(mysql_fetch_row($result));

// To store every row in the $array
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
    $array[] = $row; 
} 
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Please add some bit of explanation instead of a code only answer. While this may work, the OP should also now WHY and HOW it works.